# bash and csh script set variable equal to itself divided by a number

Tags: bash, variables, csh

This seems extremely easy but I"ve searched all over and tried all sorts of ways and it never works.

All I want to do is set a variable equal to itself divided by a constant:

Like:  $var4 = $var4/27773173 , never does the math.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=file.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,

[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
do
$var4 = $var4/27773173
/usr/bin/php ./command.php $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4 $var5

done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

I'd like to know how to do it in bash and csh...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$var4 = $var4/27773173
```

should be like

```
(( var4 = var4 / 27773173 ))
```

or simply

```
(( var4 /= 27773173 ))
```

And you can further simplify your code as a whole and keep it safe from word splitting with

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=file.csv
[[ ! -f $INPUT ]] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }

while IFS=, read var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
do
  # (( var4 /= 27773173 ))
  echo "var4 = $var4"  ## for debugging only
  var4=$(echo "scale = 2; $var4 / 27773173" | bc)
  echo "var4 (processed) = $var4"  ## for debugging only
  /usr/bin/php ./command.php "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4" "$var5"
done < "$INPUT"
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I'm used to csh...would you know the csh equivalent by chance?

Comment: @Corepuncher I don't know csh sorry :)

Comment: Only other thing is that it evaulates fractional numbers as 0 instead of decimals.  Do I need to declare it in the shell script somehow?

Comment: @Corepuncher You could use `bc` for that instead. e.g. `var4=$(echo "$var4 / 27773173" | bc)`

Comment: How many decimals places could you allow? You could also use `printf -v` to format it e.g. `printf -v var4 "%0.2f" "$(echo "$var4 / 27773173" | bc)"`

Comment: I tried this:  var4 = $(echo "$var4/27773173" | bc) , and it says "var4: command not found"

Comment: It appears you actually need to set the scale variable in bc to process by float numbers sorry. So the first method might be enough: `var4=$(echo "scale = 2; $var4 / 27773173" | bc)`

Comment: @Corepuncher You musn't add a space when defining variables.

Comment: Sorry to say, it keeps echo'ing either a 1 or a 0.

Comment: @Corepuncher Mind sharing a sample input from your file? You should make sure that you're getting the proper values every line.

Comment: Here is a line:
    JUA,18.118,-66.079,3667000,San Juan
But I think what I might do is just make the change in excel and then regenerate the csv file and just read the value that way.

Comment: @Corepuncher I updated the code. Please check. Make sure you run it with bash as well e.g. `bash script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness you can do this directly in csh with

```
@ var= $var / 27773173
```

note the spaces shown are required..and this works only for integers

Beware csh arithmetic does not follow the usual order of operations so I'd avoid it for anything remotely complicated.